# What exactly is GStreamer and should I install it?

Tags: video, 17.04, gstreamer, quicktime

I didn't ever care much about codecs, as all mostly worked. Now I have a file which seems to be QuickTime. After a brief search I think I need GStreamer. That has various plugins like good,  bad, ugly, nice, etc.

Also there are some wrappers like `ubuntu-restricted-extras`. When I try to install that, I get:

```
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libavcodec57 libavcodec57:i386 oxideqt-codecs
```

And I read around the web that people have issues after these changes.

My question:
What is GStreamer, how does it compare to what's in Ubuntu (17.04) by default, what does it conflict with and why, and can it break my current state (i.e. some formats stop playing, worse performance, tearing, broken subtitles, sound channels etc.?)

Excuse me if it doesn't make much sense but it reflects my confusion about all this :) Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To quote this post from [the gstreamer-devel mailing list](http://gstreamer-devel.966125.n4.nabble.com/What-s-the-difference-between-ffmpeg-and-gstreamer-tp4664295p4664310.html):

> ffmpeg/libav is a library that contains all kinds of codecs, support
>   for  various container formats, some filters, etc. It's a library
>   providing  some API to use these things separately.
>
> GStreamer is one level/layer above that and a generic multimedia 
>   framework, based on pipeline graphs (check Wikipedia for the pipes and
>   filters software design pattern for example). It allows you to put 
>   together arbitrary multimedia processing pipelines built from
>   different  components (we call them elements) that all do different
>   tasks.  GStreamer provides generic mechanisms to put together these
>   pipelines,  control them, synchronize data flow, etc.
>
> Some of these elements are for example decoders, that could for
>   example  be implemented by using ffmpeg/libav. Others could be filters
>   or  elements that read data from a network stream, or write data to a
>   file,  or ...

It doesn't compare because there's nothing to compare with in the default Ubuntu. KDE systems use Phonon, which I think plays the same role.

As for the conflicts, you probably didn't run `apt-get update`. `ubuntu-restricted-extras` indirectly depends on `libavcodec57`:

- `ubuntu-restricted-extras`

  - `ubuntu-restricted-addons`

    - `gstreamer1.0-libav`

      - `libavcodec57`